# Git - Cleanup squashed branches?

Tags: git

I understand how to delete branches that have been merged into master (http://stevenharman.net/git-clean-delete-already-merged-branches). How do I delete branches that have been squashed, then merged into master?

For example:

```
C:\source [master]> git checkout -b feature-a-inprogress
C:\source [feature-a-inprogress]> git ac "WIP"
C:\source [feature-a-inprogress]> git ac "WIP"
C:\source [feature-a-inprogress]> git checkout master
C:\source [master]> git checkout -b feature-a-complete
C:\source [feature-a-complete]> git merge --squash feature-a-inprogress
C:\source [feature-a-complete]> git ac "Completed Feature A"
C:\source [feature-a-complete]> git push origin feature-a-complete
```

When I run the above cleanup it would delete *Feature-A-Complete*, but not *Feature-A-InProgress*. If you were to compare the current state of *Feature-A-Complete* and *Feature-A-InProgress* they would be identical (though their histories would be different).

I understand that deleting *Feature-A-InProgress* isn’t necessarily safe because the intermediate versions would be lost, but in this case I don’t care because the final state was committed to master.

Thanks!

*edit: fixed inconsistent branch names in example*

Comment: `git ac` is not a real command. You shouldn't assume that everybody is using your custom aliases.

Comment: Also, why don't you just `git checkout master; git merge --squash feature-a-inprogress` instead of creating a useless intermediate branch?

Comment: @meagar Ah, I thought that was common, but my ac is defined as `ac = !git add --all . && git commit -am`, also everything goes through a Github pull request so nobody directly modifies master.

Comment: `git branch -D feature-a-done`? (Or `feature-a-complete`?)

Comment: @Steve The use of that `ac` alias of yours is a pretty bad habit. Ideally, you should take the time to craft your commits carefully, instead of staging and committing stuff willy-nilly.

Comment: @Jubobs I can see what changes were made after executing ac and always review changes made before issuing a PR so garbage doesn't end up in master.

Answer (score 1):

When you merge a source branch, **branch_A**, into target branch, **branch_B**, with `--squash` git will put the working tree in the same state as with a *normal* merge, but, it will not stage the change, not creating a new merge commit (with multiple parents). You have to stage and commit this change. This means that the merge source (branch_A) is not referenced from this new commit. The source branch (branch_A) can therefore be removed with `git branch -D branch_A`

```
git co branch_B
git merge --squash branch_A
git add .
git commit -m "Merge commit (C)"
```

This will result in:

```
o-o-o-B (branch_B)         o-o-o-B-C (branch_B)
   \                 ==>      \
    o-A (branch_A)             o-A (branch_A)
```